# Installing QT SDK - Windows 7 64bit

Tags: qt, windows-7, qt4, 64-bit, qt-creator

I’m trying to install qt, but giving this error in installation.

Errors:

```
    C: \ QtSDK / Madde / targets / harmattan-nokia-Meego-api / bin / qmake.exe is not existing or not executable
operation 'SetExamplesPathOnQt' with arguments: 'C: \ QtSDK / Madde / targets / harmattan-nokia-api-Meego C: \ QtSDK/Examples/4.7' failed: The output of
C: \ QtSDK \ Madde \ targets \ harmattan-nokia-Meego-api \ bin \ qmake.exe-query
  is not parseable. Please file a bugreport with this dialog http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com.
output: ""

"create message box with identifier 'installationErrorWithRetry'"
operation 'QtPatch' with arguments: 'windows C: \ QtSDK / Simulator / Qt / mingw' failed: Qt patch error: Can not open C: / QtSDK / Simulator / Qt / mingw / bin / qmake.exe


qpatch: warning: could not patched the demo path in C: \ QtSDK / Simulator / Qt / mingw / bin / qmake.exe
  ElevatedExecuteOperation setNativeArguments to start: C: \ QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/SymbianSR1Qt474/patch.qmake.paths.bat
C: \ QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/SymbianSR1Qt474/patch.qmake.paths.bat started, arguments:

qpatch: warning: could not patched in the example path C: / QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/qmake.exe
qpatch: warning: file `C: / QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/qmake.exe 'can not open.



**Qt version is not Properly installed, please run make install**
```

Anyone know why this error with this? I would be very grateful for the help.

Thank you

Comment: Please indicate the exact name of the package you downloaded from Qt and exactly what you typed or ran to perform the install.

Comment: Find out how to fix this error.
Need to disable antivirus, and place sharing windows xp (service pack 2).

Answer (score 1):

This has already been mentioned in the comments, but just so that other users can find the answer.
In windows, this is mainly an issue of the antivirus. 
Disable the antivirus while installing qt.